# what is window.show in javascript?

Tags: javascript

can someone explain for me what is window.show in this javascript code below pleae?`

```js
   <script>
 let liEls = document.querySelectorAll('ul li');
        let index = 0;
        let max = liEls.length-1;
        
        window.show = function (increase) {

            if(index==max)
            {
                index=-1;
            }
            index = index + increase;
           
        
     
            liEls[index].scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });   
            
            console.log(index);

        }
```

`

Comment: it's a function

Comment: yes , but when using for example window.open the code is not working , what is the difference?

Comment: the difference? between window.open (a "native" function) and window.show (a function created by you)? One is native, the other isn't. Neither of them will do anything until you invoke them of course ... all you've done there is defined the function, you haven't called the function

Comment: Or did you copy this function from somewhere and want us to explain this?

Comment: I saw this on youtube and it works perfectly but i didn't get the window.show what its doing here

Comment: oh, so you want to know what the function does, not what it is

Answer (score 3):

By the looks of it, the code is trying to assign an anonymous function to the global window object with a new method called .show().
It takes a value *increase* and adds it to the index of the array **liEls** (bad name by the way) defined on the very top of the code, the array calls the .querySelectorAll() method and collects all the *li* elements nested in *ul* in the html file.

Upon it's call (implying it works correctly) the window.show() method scrolls smoothly to a given *li* element

Comment: so the window.show only defining the function here,am i correct?

Comment: @ezgi it's not defining the function, the function is being assigned to the global window object as a method with the name *show*

Comment: *ul or li* ... no just a given li ... the selector is `ul li` not `ul,li` - so, ultimately, `liEls` will be (as the variable name suggests) `li` elements only - not sure why you copied the code verbatim in your answer ... padding?

Comment: @Jaromanda you are correct, I'm sorry it was a mistake on my part, I edited my answer and removed the code.